# Why are these two constraint equations not equivalent?

Tags: optimization, cplex, linearization, big-m, indicator-constraints

I've made a CP Model of an hospital in ILOG CPLEX and I want to test the performance of the CPLEX version of it.

In my CP model, I have the following constraint :

```
forall(c in Chirurgiens, o1 in Operations, o2 in Operations : o1 != o2){
    (zeta[o1][o2]==1 ) => psi[o1]+TP[o1]+TC[o1]+ max_time >= psi[o2]+TP[o2];}
```

where *zeta* is a boolean and all other variable are Integers.

I've tried to linearize it using a **big M** and it gave me the following thing :

```
   forall(c in Chirurgiens, o1 in Operations, o2 in Operations : o1 != o2){
    (psi[o1]+TP[o1]+TC[o1]+ max_time) >= psi[o2]+TP[o2] -M*(1-zeta[o1,o2]);}
```

These two constraint gave me the same result.

But now, I was cleaning my code a little bit and transformed this constraint into the following one :

```
forall(c in Chirurgiens, o1 in Operations, o2 in Operations : o1 != o2){
    (psi[o1]+TP[o1]+TC[o1]+ max_time) - psi[o2]+TP[o2] >= 0 - M*(1-zeta[o1,o2]);}
```

But now this give me a **different result**

The only thing that I've changed is that I've moved the `psi[o2]+TP[o2]` on the other side of the inequality. Isn't this supposed to be a legal move in math ?

Comment: Does the sign for TP[o2] is negative instead of positive?

Comment: omg, the whole problem was that i forgot how to do basic maths !
Thanks for you answer, i was stuck on this for hours !